# When were the various frequency Z80 CPUs introduced?

Tags: history, z80

The Z80 was introduced, as I understand it, at a clock speed of 2 MHz. Later, Z80-based computers at 3.5 MHz started showing up.

In what year did this faster clock speed become available? (In production quantity, not just samples.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Zilog Z80 (2.5 MHz) was introduced in 1976.

In 1977, the Z80A (4 MHz) was available for [$65 for the ceramic package and $59 for the plastic version](https://web.archive.org/web/20220429214057/http://www.old-computers.com/history/detail.asp?n=33&t=3).

The Z80B (6 MHz) was available in [August, 1980](https://archive.org/details/Infoworld-1980-08-04) (p. 18) if not earlier.

The Z80H (8 MHz) was introduced in [October, 1982](https://archive.org/details/Infoworld-1982-10-18) (p. 1).

Comment: *all the citations* have been taken down :(

Comment: @JacobKrall The first one's still up. The latter two are down.

Comment: Weird, it wasn’t working last night, or maybe I clicked the wrong link. Thanks!

Comment: Ohh you edited it haha